# Remote access a server with only ipv6. Avaliable approaches?

Tags: ipv6, port-forwarding, ipv4, tunnel

Recently I changed my ISP.
This new ISP provides me a real IPv6, and IPv4 behind a CGNAT, so, no way to configure DMZ or port forward.

I set up a linux server (Ubuntu Server) which want to access via SSH and HTTP and HTTPS (nginx) from my job.
The ISP of my job provides only IPv4 (real IPv4).

What are my options to make a connection from a ipv4 only client to a ipv6 only server? I like a fast way to connect to the server on Windows and Android devices. If I don't need to install any applications on clients, it would be perfect

I am newbie in a matter of ipv6.

Reading a little, I think my options are:

- Tunnel Broker: Read a little about SixXS and Hurricane. Tried Hurricane (tunnelbroker.net), but I really don't understand how this works, because to make a tunnel, I need a IPv4 with ICMP (not possible with my IPv4).
- A "generic" tunnel: I have a DigitalOcean and a Iniz server with IPv4 and IPv6. Maybe it's possible to redirect all connections from iniz/digitalocean on specified ports to a remote host, like:
  [Client] --> [INIZ/DigitalOcean] --> [HomeServer].

Any other (and maybe correct) approach? For the second alternative, what is necessary?

Thanks.

Comment: I have a [service](http://v4-frontend.netiter.com/) which depending on your exact needs might be suitable for you. Some of the information on that page is a bit out of date, but the service remains operational, and my current intention is to keep it running. It supports HTTP and HTTPS as long as the client supports HTTP/1.1 and SNI. SSH is more problematic and requires patching the client or using a `ProxyCommand`. A tunnel is certainly also a possibility - but requires each client to configure a tunnel. I'll write an answer explaining this in detail later (don't have the time right now.)

Comment: @kasperd thanks! I will check, but I think I resolved my problems using a external server (second approach) with socat. check https://ef.gy/forwarding-ipv4-to-ipv6. I made just a quick test and ssh and http worked without any problem.

Comment: After I post the question, I found several answers for the second approach, that seens be better for my problems. For who has the same problem than me, check: https://ef.gy/forwarding-ipv4-to-ipv6, http://superuser.com/questions/1004000/ipv4-connectivity-to-ipv6-only-host?rq=1, http://www.haproxy.org/, http://superuser.com/questions/982113/accessing-an-ipv6-server-with-an-ipv4-address?rq=1 and http://www.internetsociety.org/deploy360/resources/making-content-available-over-ipv6/

Comment: There's no point in using an IPv6 tunnel at home. You don't need it there! You need it somewhere else, where you haven't got IPv6 connectivity, for example at the coffee house on their Wi-Fi. SixXS should work but I think they aren't accepting new signups.